# Snakemake variable number of files

Tags: snakemake

I'm in a situation, where I would like to scatter my workflow into a variable number of chunks, which I don't know beforehand. Maybe it is easiest to explain the problem by being concrete:

Someone has handed me FASTQ files demultiplexed using `bcl2fastq` with the `no-lane-splitting` option. I would like to split these files according to lane, map each lane individually, and then finally gather everything again. However, I don't know the number of lanes beforehand.

Ideally, I would like a solution like this,

```
rule split_fastq_file: (...)  # results in N FASTQ files
rule map_fastq_file: (...)  # do this N times
rule merge_bam_files: (...)  # merge the N BAM files
```

but I am not sure this is possbile. The `expand` function requires me to know the number of lanes, and can't see how it would be possible to use wildcards for this, either.

I should say that I am rather new to Snakemake, and that I may have complete misunderstood how Snakemake works. It has taken me some time to get used to think about things "upside-down" by focusing on output files and then working backwards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use `checkpoint` when splitting the fastqs, so that you can dynamically re-evaluate the DAG at a later point to get the resulting lanes.

Here's an MWE step by step:

- Setup and make an example fastq file.

```
# Requires Python 3.6+ for f-strings, Snakemake 5.4+ for checkpoints
import pathlib
import random

random.seed(1)

rule make_fastq:
    output:
        fastq = touch("input/{sample}.fastq")
```

- Create a random number of lanes between 1 and 9 each with random identifier from 1 to 9. Note that we declare this as a `checkpoint`, rather than a rule, so that we can later access the result. Also, we declare the output here as a directory specific to the sample, so that we can later glob in it to get the lanes that were created.

```
checkpoint split_fastq:
    input:
        fastq = rules.make_fastq.output.fastq
    output:
        lane_dir = directory("temp/split_fastq/{sample}")
    run:
        pathlib.Path(output.lane_dir).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        n_lanes = random.randrange(1, 10)-
        lane_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 10), k = n_lanes)
        for lane_number in lane_numbers:
            path = pathlib.Path(output.lane_dir) / f"L00{lane_number}.fastq"
            path.touch()
```

- Do some intermediate processing.

```
rule map_fastq:
    input:
        fastq = "temp/split_fastq/{sample}/L00{lane_number}.fastq"
    output:
        bam = "temp/map_fastq/{sample}/L00{lane_number}.bam"
    run:
        bam = pathlib.Path(output.bam)
        bam.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        bam.touch()
```

- To merge all the processed files, we use an input function to access the lanes that were created in `split_fastq`, so that we can do a dynamic `expand` on these. We do the `expand` on the last rule in the chain of intermediate processing steps, in this case `map_fastq`, so that we ask for the correct inputs.

```
def get_bams(wildcards):
    lane_dir = checkpoints.split_fastq.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    lane_numbers = glob_wildcards(f"{lane_dir}/L00{{lane_number}}.fastq").lane_number
    bams = expand(rules.map_fastq.output.bam, **wildcards, lane_number=lane_numbers)
    return bams
```

- This input function now gives us easy access to the bam files we wish to merge, however many there are, and whatever they may be called.

```
rule merge_bam:
    input:
        get_bams
    output:
        bam = "temp/merge_bam/{sample}.bam"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output.bam}"
```

This example runs, and with `random.seed(1)` happens to create three lanes (`l001`, `l002`, and `l005`).

If you don't want to use `checkpoint`, I think you could achieve something similar by creating an input function for `merge_bam` that opens up the original input fastq, scans the read names for lane info, and predicts what the input files ought to be. This seems less robust, however.

Comment: Thanks for this useful example. Is the `bam.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True)` really necessary? I thought directory creation was taken in charge by snakemake.

Comment: @bli: Usually yes, and I was also surprised. I hadn't included it in the beginning and got an error. `Path.touch()` seems to require the dir to exist, and fails without the `Path.mkdir()`, so I guess Snakemake has not yet created the directory at that point, or works in some temp dir that is moved later? Not sure, and since it was just to get the MWE running, I didn't spend too much time digging here. I'd be happy to hear it if someone has an explanation.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about the input function `get_bams`? In particular what's in the `wildcards` dictionary at that point? i.e. what's being passed to `checkpoints.split_fastq.get`?