# How to build a snakemake workflow with variable number of input files using checkpoints?

Tags: snakemake

I am quite new to the Snakemake practice. I would like to process a set of files in my Snakemake workflow of which I don't know in advance the file name or the number of input files. The input files are obtained with a function that accesses some remote files based on some parameters such as:

`data =  dataset(datatype=datatype, eventtype=eventtype, polarity=polarity)`

`data` is a list of locations of remote files that I'd like to process but of which I don't know in advance the length or the filename since they depend on the parameters passed to the function `dataset`. The workflow should be such that the data is remotely accessed, processed locally and then finally merged.

I tried using `checkpoints` based on the example that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792649/snakemake-variable-number-of-files) however I am failing to understand how to adapt it to my needs. Here is what I tried:

```
rule get_ap_loc:
    output:
        # data = dataset(datatype="2016", eventtype="11104043", polarity="magup")
        data = ["path1", "path2", "path3"]


checkpoint split_data:
    input:
        data_loc = rules.get_ap_loc.output.data
    output:
        outdir = directory("temp/split_jobs/")
    run:
        pathlib.Path(output.outdir).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        subjob_numbers=[]
        for subjob_number, remotepath in enumerate(input.data_loc):
            with open(os.path.join(f'{output.outdir}',f'{subjob_number}.txt'), "w") as file:
                file.write(remotepath)
                subjob_numbers.append(subjob_number)


#processes the ith root subjob
rule process_job:
    input:
        subjob = "temp/split_jobs/{subjob_number}.txt"
    output:
        processed = "temp/split_jobs/{subjob_number}.root"
    run:
        stuff = pathlib.Path(output.processed)
        stuff.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        stuff.touch()

#collects paths to all root subjobs
def get_all_subjobs(wildcards):
    subjob_dir = checkpoints.split_data.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    subjob_numbers = glob_wildcards(f"{subjob_dir}/{{subjob_number}}.txt").subjob_number
    all_subjobs = expand(rules.process_job.output.bam, **wildcards, subjob_number=subjob_numbers)
    return all_subjobs


#will hadd root subjobs
rule merge_subjobs:
    input:
        get_all_subjobs
    output:
        hadded = "temp/merge_root/hadded.root"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output.hadded}"
```

Are checkpoints supposed to deal with these cases?

Thanks